# ext js 6 pagination not working

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am having a problem with my ext js. I am trying to build pagination on a grid panel and get data from REST. The data is showing but pagination is not working.

Here is my code:

```
pageSize: 5,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',

    url : 'http://localhost/kds-rest/web/index.php/volunteer',
    useDefaultXhrHeader : false,
    withCredentials: false,
    reader: {
       type: 'json'
        //type: 'json',
        //rootProperty: 'topics',
        //totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        //totalProperty: 'totalCount'
    },
    enablePaging : true
},
autoLoad: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code for your grid I can only guess that you don't have the store declared on the paging toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the proxy to be [`Ext.data.proxy.Ajax`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax), which is a kind of [`Ext.data.proxy.Server`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server).

[`enablePaging`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory-cfg-enablePaging) property is only available on [`Ext.data.proxy.Memory`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory), which does not support XMLHttpRequest calls to URLs.

If you want to use paging with Server proxies, the paging has to be done server-side: The server shall not return all records at once, but one page at a time; the page number is transmitted from the client automatically with every request in [`pageParam`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-pageParam).